# pyinstaller - collect local package

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a Python application which I want to bundel with pyinstaller.

My folder structure is like this:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── manual
├── main.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.sh
├── venv
│   └── ...
└── mypackage
    ├── package1
    ├── package2
    ├── bindata1.bin
    ├── bindata2.bin
    └── __init__.py
```

`mypackage` is a python package which also contains some binary data and does some dynamic importing by scanning some submodules/namespaces:

```py
def iter_namespace(ns_pkg):
    return pkgutil.iter_modules(ns_pkg.__path__, ns_pkg.__name__ + ".")


APPS = {}

for finder, name, ispkg in iter_namespace(apps):
    if not ispkg:
        continue
    package = importlib.import_module(name + '.app')
    APPS[package.APPNAME] = package.App
```

This works fine when running the python script directly, but not with the frozen version. My first approach was this command: `pyinstaller main.py --clean --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --hidden-import pyvisa_py`
So I tried to collect the package by appending `--collect-all mypackage`, but I get those warnings:

```
115 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.0
115 INFO: Python: 3.10.6
116 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.19.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
116 INFO: wrote /opt/mysoftware/main.spec
117 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /root/.cache/pyinstaller
121 WARNING: Unable to copy metadata for mypackage: The 'mypackage' distribution was not found and is required by the application
121 WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'mypackage' as it is not a package.
121 WARNING: collect_dynamic_libs - skipping library collection for module 'mypackage' as it is not a package.
142 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
760 WARNING: Unable to determine requirements for mypackage: The 'mypackage' distribution was not found and is required by the application
760 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/opt/mysfoftware']
898 INFO: checking Analysis
898 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
898 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
...
```

How can I get Pyinstaller to collect my package so that dynamic loading and accessing binary data works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied [rokm](https://github.com/rokm)'s from [Github discussion](https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/7853#discussioncomment-6749130), used solution 1:

> Yes, that's a limitation of how `--collect-submodules mypackage`, `--collect-data mypackage`, `--collect-binaries mypackage` work. They add calls to `collect_submodules()`, `collect_data_files()`, and `collect_dynamic_libs()` at the top of the generated .spec file, and pass the resulting lists to the Analysis instance.
>
> However, the package search paths are extended with location of your entry-point acript only during instantiation of `Analysis`. Therefore, those `collect_` calls cannot find a local (non-installed) copy of `mypackage`.
>
> There are three ways to deal with this (aside from installing mypackageto your venv):
>
> 1. write a hook for `mypackage`. I.e., create a directory called `pyinstaller-hooks`, and create a hook file called `hook-mypackage.py` inside it, with the following content:
>
> ```py
> # pyinstaller-hooks/hook-mypackage.py
> from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules, collect_data files 
> hiddenimports = collect_submodules('mypackage') 
> datas = collect_data_files('mypackage') 
> binaries = collect_dynamic_libs('mypackage')
> ```
>
> and then pass the additional hooks directory to PyInstaller via `--additional-hooks-dir ./pyinstaller-hooks`. This is how things were done before `--colllect-*` command-line "shortcuts" were added; and it works because hooks are ran during `Analysis` instantiation, so after the package search path has been extended with location of the entry-point script.
>
> 2. Use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to add the parent directory of `mypackage` to python's global search path, before running `PyInstaller`.
> 3. Edit the generated spec file and append the parent directory of `mypackage` to `sys.path` before the `collect_*` calls are made (within the context of code executed in the .spec file, there is a special variable called `SPECPATH` that points to the parent directory of the spec; you can use that as an anchor to path to parent directory of `mypackage`). Then you build your application using the modified .spec file instead of the original .py file (which would re-generate the spec and overwrite the changes).